# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^{3}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-n^{2}+\frac{1}{6})$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $t\in \mathbb R$. Prove that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{3}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-n^{2}+t}$ converges iff $t=\frac{1}{6}$.

While the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction was fairly easy (as $a_n$ should converge to $0$, forcing $t=\frac{1}{6}$), i'm facing some hard time trying to prove the second direction, that is $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^{3}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-n^{2}+\frac{1}{6})}$ converges.

I did notice that $a_n=a_{-n}$ and tried to write this series as a Leibnitz series, but had no luck since the sequence doesn't decrease.
I also tried to prove absolute convergence but then again, no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Prove the existence of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2a_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$n^3\sin\left(\frac1n\right)-n^2+\frac16=\frac{\sin\left(\frac1n\right)-\frac1n+\frac1{3!}\left(\frac1n\right)^3}{\left(\frac1n\right)^3}$$and that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}}{x^5}=\frac1{5!},$$which implies that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sin\left(\frac1n\right)-\frac1n+\frac1{3!}\left(\frac1n\right)^3}{\left(\frac1n\right)^3}}{\left(\frac1n\right)^2}=\frac1{5!}$$Now, use the fact that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: This is great, how do I show $a_n$ is non-negative? As it is sufficient in order to use the limit comparison test

Comment: You *don't* prove it's non-negative! Instead, you use what I did in order to prove that you series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1):

For the converse, you can write,

$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Therefore,

$$n^3 \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) -n^2+\dfrac{1}{6}=n^2-\dfrac{1}{6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)-n^2+\dfrac{1}{6} = O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

I let you conclude.